# Which jQuery .on() is faster: direct or delegated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, event-handling, jquery-events

Assume I need to set up `'click'` event listener on `<div class="cool-div">`. And let's say it has an ancestor.

```
<div class="cool-ancestor">
    ...
    <div class="cool-div">
    ...
</div>
```

Which of the following code I should use for better performance and why?

**a)** `$(document).on('click', '.cool-div', function(){...})`

**b)** `$('.cool-ancestor').on('click', '.cool-div', function(){...})`

**c)** `$('.cool-div').on('click', function(){...})`

**Situation 1**

- There is the only one `<div class="cool-div">` on the page.

**Situation 2**

- There are many `<div class="cool-div">` on the page.

Comment: Definetely direct.

Comment: click is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ), direct would be faster. to learn more https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Because those 1-2 milliseconds in difference will change anything

Comment: I don't know, I would have to test. But I usually prefer `b)` because I don't have to wait for `DOMContentLoaded` for my scripts to work. So even if the page is not finished loading my buttons already work.

Answer (score 1):

#### REMOVE JQUERY

If you're intressted in performance, **removing jquery** is the first thing to do. Just enjoy [Vanilla-JS performance](http://vanilla-js.com/).
JQuery is slower when it comes to select elements, that's a thing, but another reason to hate JQuery is that it automatically attaches event listeners to certains elements. 
For example, if you use *jquery 1.11*, all you `a` tags will have a `blur` and a `focus` event listener setted.

#### HOW DOES THE DOM WORK ?

If you want to build powerful apps in the navigator, you need to know how the navigator deals with your code.
So, [here is a wonderful article about DOM events](https://www.bitovi.com/blog/a-crash-course-in-how-dom-events-work)
[reflow and repaints](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/)
And [a good ressource about what will call a reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)

#### SOME GUIDELINES

If you don't have the time to read the article above, the following guildelines are to be considered :

- Keep yout HTML light (the less nested elements you have, the faster events will run through your page)
- Do not attach useless event listeners, it will just consume ressources for no reason (so -again - remove jQuery).
- Try to not trigger *reflow* because the positions and dimensions of all the elements will be recalculated. For example, CSS position changes or `input.focus()` causes *reflow*.

Hope it helps,
best regards,

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't generate any child div's

```
     <div class="cool-div">
```

Dynamically then direct is perfect and works smoothly. Else it's better to use delegated as in sometimes direct may not work for dynamically generated elements.